# JQuery - prevent multi-level dropdowns from disappearing on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I have a dropdown menu with 2 levels. On hover of the link on level 1, it opens level 2 successfully, however, when moving my mouse from level 1 to level 2, the whole menu disappears. (The dropdown menus appear on hover)

Basically what I want to achieve is on hover of level-two-dropdown, for the whole dropdown menu to not disappear and to allow the user to click on the LEVEL 2 link.

Here is my HTML for reference:

```
<ul class="link">
  <li class="level-one-link">
    <a href="" class="link-name">
        LEVEL 1 LINK
        <ul class="level-two-dropdown">
            <li class="level-two-link">
                <a href="" class="link-name">
                    LEVEL 2 LINK
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

my JQuery:

```
function displayDropDown(){
$(".link-name").on("mouseenter", function (){
    $(this).addClass("highlighted")
})

$(".link-name").on("mouseleave", function (){
    $(this).removeClass("highlighted")
})

$(".level-two-dropdown").on("mouseenter", function (){
    $(this).parent("a").addClass("highlighted")
})

$(".level-two-dropdown").on("mouseleave", function (){
    $(this).parent("a").removeClass("highlighted")
})
```

}

CSS:

```
.highlighted {display: block);
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.level-two-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
function displayDropDown(){
$(".link-name").on("mouseenter", function (){
    $('.level-two-dropdown').css("display", "block")
})
$(".link-name").on("mouseleave", function (){
    $('.level-two-dropdown').css("display", "none")
})
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

This will also work, and is cleaner:

```
function displayDropDown(){
    $(".link-name").hover(function() {
    $('.level-two-dropdown').toggle()
    })
}
```